# CDK Infinite scroll end checking

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

im trying to implement infinite scroll for loading items on to the list dynamically when user scrolls down the list, but when i access the end and total , it is coming as same, i need to check if the last item is reached and then append new items to the list. the problem is both end and total are same and gets triggered everytime

HTML

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height: 300px" itemSize="5" (scrolledIndexChange)="nextBatch($event)">
  <li *cdkVirtualFor="let row of auditDetails; let j=index;" style="height: 100px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;">{{j}}</li>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

TS

```js
auditDetails = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

ngAfterViewInit() { }

nextBatch(currIndex: number, items: any[]) {
  const start = this.viewPort.getRenderedRange().start;
  const end = this.viewPort.getRenderedRange().end;
  const total = this.viewPort.getDataLength();
  console.log(`end is ${end} total is ${total}`)
  if (end == total) {
    console.log("end reached increase page no")
  }
}

trackByIdx(i: number) {
  return i;
}
```

Stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-infinite-scroll-ufuewv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CDK documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api) the **itemSize** property is expressed in **pixels**. I think you tried to express it as a number of item, which is not correct. You should try it like that (with the **itemSize** value matching your inline styled height of 100px per item):

`itemSize="100"`

From now I can see in the output log:

```
end is 5 total is 20
end is 5 total is 20
end is 5 total is 20
end is 7 total is 20
end is 7 total is 20
end is 9 total is 20
end is 9 total is 20
end is 9 total is 20
end is 11 total is 20
end is 13 total is 20
end is 13 total is 20
end is 15 total is 20
end is 15 total is 20
end is 17 total is 20
end is 17 total is 20
end is 17 total is 20
end is 19 total is 20
end is 20 total is 20
end reached increase page no
```

Comment: thanks, cdk team should have named it as "itemSizePx" to avoid confusion